# Makefile warning flags Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, makefile

I'm using this `Makefile` to build my out-of-tree kernel module. (The module consists of only one source file.) I want to use more warning flags than the ones that come by default. The problem is that the standard Linux headers (like `#include <linux/module.h>`) are also checked for warnings and therefore tons of warnings are outputted. How can I modify this Makefile so that the standard Linux headers are not checked for warnings?

```
# to build the module: make module=mymodulename
# to clean: make clean

obj-m += $(module).o

# extra warning flags
ccflags-y := -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wall -Wextra -Wdouble-promotion -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wunused -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wno-div-by-zero -Wtrampolines -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wno-endif-labels -Wshadow -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wsync-nand -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wjump-misses-init -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wnormalized=nfc -Wpacked -Wpadded -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Wunreachable-code -Winline -Winvalid-pch -Wdisabled-optimization -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Woverlength-strings -Wunsuffixed-float-constants
# disable some warning flags
ccflags-y += -Wno-declaration-after-statement -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-conversion
# enable some extra warning flags
KBUILD_ENABLE_EXTRA_GCC_CHECKS := 3
# increase verbosity
KBUILD_VERBOSE := 1

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, for the compiler the header is *part* of the source file. It's been pasted in there by the preprocessor. So it will be difficult to enable warnings for a source file but not the headers it includes. (I know that MSVC provides some `#pragma`s for this, not sure if GCC has similar features.)

Since your module appears to be rather small, you could make the necessary declarations yourself and *not* include the headers. This really depends on how much from the headers you are using.

For example, to use `printf()` without actually including `<stdio.h>`:

```
int printf( const char * format, ... );

int main()
{
    printf( "Hello, %s.\n", "world" );
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, your declarations must match those from the header you are avoiding, or you will get into trouble at link time.

Comment: gcc has pragmas for that too: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

Comment: @nos: Nice! You know, that would probably make a very good answer to the OP's question... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment of [nos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126769/nos). Diagnostic Pragmas work.

Note that ignored warning should be used as original warning.
So flag `-Wno-declaration-after-statement` should become:

```c
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeclaration-after-statement"
```

You may refere to [GCC Diagnostic Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html)

Following is basic usage.

```c
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wuninitialized"
  foo(a);                       /* error is given for this one */
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wuninitialized"
  foo(b);                       /* no diagnostic for this one */
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
  foo(c);                       /* error is given for this one */
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
  foo(d);                       /* depends on command-line options */
```